# Using Eigen with EIGEN_USE_BLAS in iOS project

Tags: ios, eigen, blas, accelerate-framework

Out of educational purposes I'm trying to use Eigen in my pet project. In order to speed the math I included macro `EIGEN_USE_BLAS` which activates use of `blas` library.

But I encountered an issue when I tried to upload my project to Testflight. The Apple response to that was:

> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public
>   symbols in My-Project: _saxpy_, _sgemm_, _sgemv_, _strmm_,
>   _strmv_. If method names in your source code match the private Apple
>   APIs listed above, altering your method names will help prevent this
>   app from being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that
>   one or more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that
>   was included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further
>   information, visit the Technical Support Information at
>   http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

I know that Apple has `blas` library as a part of `Accelerate.framework` and it should be use strictly through Accelerate API. But the thing is that Eigen also has their own `blas` included in their source and the library actually has no intention of using `Accelerate.framework` private guts. So that is why Apple asks me to rename those functions or remove them completely in order to get rid of that inconvenience.

But I'm not even sure that it is possible to do - to tune `Eigen` and its `blas` to use alternative names.

Is there maybe a way to solve that issue in some efficient manner? Or maybe I don't know something about Eigen usage in iOS environment?

Comment: you have an x86 compiler or the arm compiler from the toolchain ?

Comment: Hello and thank you for your response! Could you elaborate what you mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was lucky to figure out the problem with few tips from my fellow colleagues and a strong will to get the job done, and now I want to share with you my conclusions.

**The problem:** Eigen doesn't have `BLAS` binary provided, it only has it's headers. And when one uses `EIGEN_USE_BLAS` macro and it actually works, that means that Apple is linking Eigen BLAS functions to their binary - `BLAS` binary which is a part of `Accelerate.framework`. The trickiest part is that your project doesn't necessarily should have `Accelerate.framework` inside. XCode will add necessary files automatically and of course it won't bother to tell you that.

What's weird for me the most here is that using "naked" `BLAS` provided by Apple's `Accelerate.framework` is a clear violation because it's private API. So... from my perspective it's kind of XCode violates this rule without my intention and tells me nothing about it. Strange...

So, in order to fix it, you need to build `BLAS` or `OpenBLAS` binary (I have built `OpenBLAS`), add it to the project and link through `Other linker flags` in `Build settings`. After that the error is gone and you're able to upload your build to Testflight.

In order to save you some time in building `OpenBLAS` for `iOS`, I will leave you few links. I think those would be enough:

http://www.programmersought.com/article/2638161057/ - very clear tutorial on how to build `OpenBLAS`
https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/tree/release-0.2.21 - source code of the library
https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS/issues/1531 - discussion where you can find solutions to problems you might encounter

What I found the most confusing part of this whole story is the message from Apple. Here's another copy of that:

> ITMS-90338: Non-public API usage - The app references non-public
>   symbols in My-Project: *saxpy*, *sgemm*, *sgemv*, *strmm*, *strmv*. If
>   method names in your source code match the private Apple APIs listed
>   above, altering your method names will help prevent this app from
>   being flagged in future submissions. In addition, note that one or
>   more of the above APIs may be located in a static library that was
>   included with your app. If so, they must be removed. For further
>   information, visit the Technical Support Information at
>   http://developer.apple.com/support/technical/

I'm not a native English speaker but I feel pretty confident to say that this text is a non-sense and has absolutely nothing to do with the solving of the actual problem.

It says absolutely nothing about the fact that private API was linked to my code and that is the problem. And that I need to provide my own backend for those functions in order to make error disappear. It says about names matching and that altering my names will help to solve the problem, when it clearly will not in my case.

I hope Apple will bring more clarity into this problem and that errors descriptions will have more sense in the future.

Comment: Did you benchmark if you are actually faster with OpenBLAS instead of using Eigen without `-DEIGEN_USE_BLAS` (but compiling with `-O2 -march=native -DNDEBUG`)?

Comment: And you could build a BLAS library using Eigen (using `make blas`). But using that as the BLAS backend will not be beneficial compared to using Eigen directly, of course.

Comment: As a matter of fact, I did a benchmark. With `EUGEN_USE_BLAS` macro Eigen was 30 times faster, give or take. On some operations it was even 80 times faster (on iPad Pro one heavy calculation was done for 33 ms, with `EIGEN_USE_BLAS` it was around 0.4 ms). In my project and with my calculations `EIGEN_USE_BLAS` matters a huge deal.

Comment: I didn't compile Eigen, I use it as it is. Do you think I should compile it into the library? What advantages I can have doing so?

Comment: As I said, you should not need to compile the Eigen-BLAS library, if you only want to use it as backend for Eigen. But you must definitely compile with optimization enabled, especially, if you don't use an external BLAS library. With optimizations enabled you should definitely not have a difference of that magnitude.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm a bit confused. I want to use BLAS optimizations implemented in Eigen, and for that I definitely must do two steps:
1) Include `EIGEN_USE_BLAS` macro
2) Provide BLAS backend

What exactly do you want to tell me by saying "But using that as the BLAS backend will not be beneficial compared to using Eigen directly, of course."?

Comment: Are you saying that with some optimizations enabled for Eigen I might achieve same result without using `BLAS`? If so, could you provide a source where I can read more about that?

Comment: Yes, using `EIGEN_USE_BLAS` is only beneficial, if you have a BLAS library which is (significantly) faster than Eigen. Without optimizations Eigen is really slow, due to the amount of expression templates (which can be optimized away). Read this: http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=FAQ#How_do_I_get_good_performance.3F

Comment: And you could build a BLAS library using Eigen (using make blas) - could you elaborate on this statement? At what place should I execute `make blas`? Is there any tutorial how to build BLAS library using Eigen?